Set Data Source of Graph to Pivot Table Row Labels range that changes in size
I have a pivot table and the number of rows on it may change as the data changes. I then have a normal graph (not pivot graph) where I plot data from the pivot table under one data series, and then data from a non-pivot table on a different data series. Is there a way to set the data series for my graph to a dynamic field range on a pivot table so that I don't need to constantly update the range when the number of rows in my pivot table changes? I tried naming the pivot table and the active fields of the pivot table, but could use neither of those in my data source expression.
I've thought about the following two workarounds:

Use power query on the original data to create the same list found on the pivot table, and name the new power query table so that it can be used as the graph's data series.
Write a macro to calculate the range on the pivot table to use for the graph's data series?

But I'm looking for possibly a more elegant solution that doesn't require additional data sources or writing of macros before I resort to these options.

The simplest way to do it would be to use a defined dynamic range, for example something like:
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A), 1)


Go to the Formulas tab and select Name Manager.
Click New to create a new named range.
For the Name, enter something descriptive like PivotData.
In the Refers to box, use the OFFSET function (as shown above, adjusted to suit your pivot table data) to define the range dynamically.

You can do it similar formulas for series and data.

Thanks Michael! I couldn't figure out how to remove the header rows from the pivot table so as not to include it in the graph, but just subtracted two from the COUNTA calculation, and it seemed to do the trick.
